# div onClick function fires after state change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an issue where a function is being called after state is changed in a React application.

I've looked at the other solutions provided on here but it's still not working for me. Maybe it's because my click is on a div and not on an input.

Any advice would be appreciated!

The function in question is the handleClick function. When I trigger a state change on the Video Deck the function is called and I absolutely do not want this to happen.

Code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

// COMPONENTS
import VideoDeck from './deck/videoDeck'
import VideoPlayer from './video/videoPlayer'

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    super (props, context)

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick () {
    console.log('click')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div id="main" className="cls-main" onClick={() => {this.handleClick()}}>
        <div id="player-overlay" className="cls-player-overlay">
          <br />
        </div>
        <VideoPlayer />
        <VideoDeck />
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return state;
  }
)(Main)
```

Comment: Is it because you are calling the function in the onClick - should it not be - onClick={() => {this.handleClick}

Comment: Try removing the bind in the constructor?

Comment: @dmoo If I do that, then the function doesn't fire at all

Comment: @Raymond Nope, still the same

Comment: Sounds like the `click` event is triggered before the state change. All registered listeners will be triggered even if react has re-rendered. I can't really help you much without knowing the particular of the use case. But there's not really a magic solution in this case. You'll want to manually skip function execution, or stop the click event from propagating and calling further listeners with `stopImmediatePropagation`

Comment: Assume you have seen this - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Not part of this question, however, what is the difference between `onClick={this.handleClick}` and `onClick={() = > this.handleClick}`? I guess, it should work, if you simply write it as `onClick={this.handleClick}`

Comment: @Ankit I don't know how to explain it 100% but the first way will call the function when the component is rendered, while the second method will only execute when the click happens. That's what supposed to happen, anyway.

Comment: I think the problem is the div. I just tried it with a button and then it works fine, as expected. wtf hahah.

Comment: Have you tried `onClick={this.handleClick}`?

Comment: @Ankit Yup, doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Just so you know, second parameter of `connect` function needs to null or a function. It should not be undefined.

Comment: @Stef Could you show `VideoDeck`? I want to know how you trigger a state change.

Comment: @fumi_hwh It's ok, I can actually carry on with the application without this affecting what I need to do.